# Was Corman's The Day the World Ended cited as inspiration for 10 Cloverfield Lane?

Tags: inspiration, cloverfield, 10-cloverfield-lane, day-the-world-ended-1955

The Corman movie has a man (and his daughter) living in a well-stocked house after a nuclear attack. However, unexpected people show up. In both movies, the "prepper" is ex-navy and Goodman even physically resembles the guy in the 1955 flick. But I see no mention that the newer flick was inspired by Corman's -- I would like to see an acknowledgement if indeed Corman's flick inspired J. J. Abrams or the writers.

Comment: The protagonist being a military or ex-military man is a very common trend. An useful one, as it provides a backstory that may explain his training, his ideas, his traumas... Also some societies tend to idealize the military, so it could make him more sympathetic to the public. That is the only relationship between the two works?

Comment: Trachtenberg has said that the big inspiration was Psycho, and various video games. I've not seen him mention Corman's film